# Response Assertion / Regex Extractor Not Working in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to extract the CSRF token so I can log in, and be able to obtain cookies, but I'm not able to.

I'm able to get a 200 response code when accessing the URL that contains the CSRF token, and I'm able to see it on the browser and the console, but my response assertion is not able to assert anything regardless of me changing the apply to, field to test, and pattern matching rules sections. My regular expression extractor isn't able to get anything either. All the headers to get to the URL are there. Any suggestions?

Forgot to mention, I'm able to get it on one server that's exactly (or should be) exactly the same as this one...

[image: Response Assertion]

[image: Regular Expression]

EDIT:

I placed it under the HTTP Sampler that has that response, and here is an example of what I get for my response assertion. I've also added various images.

[image: test plan structure]

[image: response assertion that will later fail]

[image: failed response]

[image: json token I'm trying to extract]

[image: json extractor]

Comment: Please be more specific in your questions, what do you want to achieve? If it is extracting the token then use JSON Extractor exactly under the http sampler which provides token as the response. Store the token in a variable and use it in another subsequent requests. What is the use of your response assertion in your test plan? You can't use regular expressions to match in Response assertion. That's why response assertion got failed.

Comment: @Jahan, I guess my question is, why does my regex extractor, now JSON extractor, not extract the token? For the response assertion, I'm looking at the text in the browser, which contains "token" as a text, I didn't mean it as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't share your output, so I cannot tell for sure, but although it seems your RegEx is correct in both cases, it could be that it doesn't match due to some extra spacing.

It appears that you are expecting a valid JSON, so instead of RegEx you could use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and/or [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion), for which extra spacing will not matter.

Example: if Response Data is

> ```
> {"token":"12345"}
> ```

I can specify JSON Extractor as

[image]

(most important line is **JSON Path**: `$.token`)

and the result will be variable `token` with value `12345`.

[Here's](http://jsonpath.com/) a good online JSON Path tester, which can help you to figure out the right JSON Path.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! My response data is in the same format as yours, but my value contains various letters, numbers, and a dot and a dash. I tried it just like you did it, and on jsonpathonline it shows that $.token would work, but when I put it in my code on the same level as the HTTP samplers, and within one, it didn't work :( Do you have any ideas? Do you know how I would store it? I'm seeing that the suffix_ALL checkbox could do it, but I have to store it in a specific variable... @kiril-s

Comment: it should be **under** HTTP Sampler which has that token as response, not next to it. Also you need to share how your plan looks like, as well as example of response which has that token

Comment: Hi @kiril-s, I changed my JSON extractor to be under the HTTP Sampler that returns a token as a response. Also, I included more pictures that show my response, and what I'm hoping to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to check presence of a [JSON Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) with name of `token` and an arbitrary value I would recommend going for [JSON Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) instead.

1. Add JSON Assertion as a child of the request you would like to assert.
2. Use the following [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples) query:

   ```
   $.token
   ```

   [image: JMeter JSON Path Assertion]

JSON Assertion is available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

---

If you still want to go for the Response Assertion - configure it as follows:

- Pattern Matching Rules: `Contains`
- Patterns to Test: `{"token":"(.+?)"}`

[image: JMeter Response Assertion Regex Mode]